# Spring MVC Request method 'POST' not supported -> HTTP 405

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

Got stuck for ~4 hours wondering where is the mistake in Spring MVC/thymeleaf app. 
 My local goal is to render admin.html after submitting login/pass form at home page.

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
        @GetMapping("/")
        public String getHome(Model m) {
            m.addAttribute( "user",new User());
            return "/home";
        }
        @PostMapping("/")
        public String getSubmit(@ModelAttribute User user){

            return "/admin";
        }
}
```

home.html:

```
  <form action="#" th:action="@{/admin}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
            <p class="txt">Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/></p>
            <p class="txt">Password: <input type="text" th:field="*{password}"/></p>
            <p><input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                <input class="button" type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
        </form >
```

User class:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private boolean isAdmin;
    private String address;
}
```

So I have googled loads of ideas, removed spring security from pom.xml,
tried to use @RequestedMapping with RequestMethod.PUT , - no way , it doesn't work.

Comment: th:action="@{/admin}" - redirects to api  -> /admin and you don't have that api in controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller should be like this:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getHome(Model m) {
        m.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "/home";
    }

    @PostMapping("/admin")
    public String getSubmit(User user) {   
        return "/admin";
    }
}
```

home.html shoud be like:

```
<form action="@{/admin}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
    <p class="txt">Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/></p>
    <p class="txt">Password: <input type="text" th:field="*{password}"/></p>
    <p><input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input class="button" type="reset" value="Reset"/></p>
</form >
```

Answer (score 2):

Your form references `th:action="@{/admin}"` as target. Your controller does not map `/admin` but only root `/`.

You have to change your target to `/`.

If you want to render a template `/admin` then your return is correct. If you want to redirect to `/admin` so a new controller may handle this, so you have to write `redirect:/admin` instead.

Comment: Changing the target doesn't work. I wrote AdminController, but it looks terrible adding new Controller on every move. Thanks anyway!